# matrices equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A, B, J 4x4 matrcies, such that:
$\eqalign{
  & {A^t}JA = J  \cr 
  & {B^t}JB = J \cr} $

Prove that:
${(AB)^t}J(AB) = J$

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

1. $(AB)^t = B^tA^t$
2. $(AB)^tJ(AB)=B^t(A^tJA)B$

Comment: Wonderful, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$(AB)^T J (AB) = B^T A^T J A B = B^T \Big(A^T J A\Big) B = ... ?$$